# Как с помощью регулярного выражения и preg_replace добавить класс к тегу <a> PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Вопрос следующий:

как из такой строки:    `<a title="2" href="link" class="pagenav"></a>` 
получить такую:      `<a title="2" href="link" class="pagenav MYCLASS"></a>`

Другими словами, как с помощью регулярного выражения в preg_replace добавить класс к тегу?

P.S.: если есть другие варианты как это сделать, кроме preg_replace, буду очень признательна.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '<a title="2" href="link" class="pagenav"></a>';
$pattern = '/<a .*class="pagenav">([^<]*)<\/a>/i';
$replace = '<a title="2" href="link" class="pagenav MYCLASS">$1</a>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $str);
```

Хотя, корректней было бы использовать ([^<]+), но в вашем примере оно бы не работало =)

Comment: работает, спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
// добавляемый класс, состоит только из букв и цифр
$addclass = 'MYCLASS';
// класс к которому добавляем, состоит только из букв и цифр
$needcalss = 'pagenav';
// непередаваемый набор символов понятный для функции preg_replace
$pattern = '%<a [^<>]*class="(?![^"]*?\b' . $addclass . '\b)[^"]*?\b' . $needcalss . '\b\K%i';

$text = '<a title="2" href="link" class="pagenav2">1</a>' . "\n" . '<a title="2" href="link" class="pagenav">2</a>' . "\n" . '<a title="2" href="link" class="pagenav MYCLASS">3</a>';
$text = preg_replace($pattern, ' ' . $addclass, $text);

echo $text;
```

Песочница для тестов [тут](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/47278e736987c086672510e2546f11a422b046eb).

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
$html = '<a title="2" href="link" class="pagenav"></a>';
echo preg_replace('/class="([^"]+)"/i', 'class="$1 MYCLASS"', $html);
```